# How rational is it to use Intel Realsense for my affordable indoor autonomous robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, raspberry-pi

Right now, I am using ESP32 for the motors and planning to add either Raspberry Pi Zero or ARM Cortex-M4 (STM32) and use ROS with Intel RealSense RGBD camera.

How sensible is it? I am not expert in hardware and asking whether this will be rational and would such camera be computationally expensive? I am planing to do vSLAM with it.

Answer (score 1):

The Realsense sensors are reasonable to use on indoor autonomous robots.

"Affordable" is subjective, so I've left it out of my above response.

And if you want to use it make sure that you have enough compute capability and USB bus available to stream the data coming off the sensors. Depending on your use case and settings, smaller processors like the ones you're listing may have trouble operating on the full speed data.

Note that there's also some new information about [future availability of Realsense sensors](https://discourse.ros.org/t/intel-cancelling-its-realsense-business-alternatives/21881/27)